# Comment formatting with comment_content

Tags: formatting, comments

I'm displaying a comment outside the comment template, getting it with `get_comments()` and echoing the `comment_content`. My problem is that the comment loses the formatting (paragraphs, line breaks, etc...). In my template I'm using [TinyMCEComments](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymcecomments/) (TinyMCE on comment form).

Someone pointed me to this solution, but is not working for me.

```
<?php echo wpautop($comment->comment_content);?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

applying the 'the_content' filter could work:

```
<?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $comment->comment_content); ?>
```

Comment: I wasn't looking for the_content in codex, I was looking into get_comments...thanks for the tip, I'm putting it in my deck!

Answer (score 0):

Try `$GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment` above that function.